# join two tables and fetch result in two array

Tags: php, arrays, join, mysqli

I have two tables and make join by `groupid`:

```
$UserInfo= db::Query("SELECT g.* AS GroupPer ,u.* As Userinfo ,
(SELECT COUNT(m.id) FROM     ".DATABASE_TP_PREFIX."comments m  WHERE  m.userid =u.userid ) AS totalcomments
FROM ".DATABASE_TP_PREFIX."user u LEFT JOIN ".DATABASE_TP_PREFIX."userprofile p ON u.userid=p.parentid
LEFT JOIN ".DATABASE_TP_PREFIX."groups g ON g.id=u.groupid
WHERE u.userid=".$Userid."");
```

I need fetch results as two array (the above result one array) 
Forexample :

```
$this->Info = db::fetch_array($UserInfo,'assoc');       // user info
$this->Permission = db::fetch_array($UserInfo,'assoc'); // user Permission
```

like this

```
array (
    array[0] (
        username => Manour,
        email    => Eimaidwra@zzzz.com
    )
    array[1] (
        group_tite      => Administer,
        permissonaccess => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you have currently?

Comment: The result is one array array (
        username => Manour,
        email    => Eimaidwra@zzzz.com,
        group_tite      => Administer,
        permissonaccess => 1
    )